# Preparing plank subfloor for new flooring

Tags: subfloor, leveling

I recently bought a house that was built in 1890. Due to the age of the house and some previous issues and general lack of upkeep, the original floors need to be replaced. I plan on laying plywood over the old floor, but I have run into a couple of issues that I'm trying to find the right solution to. The first issue that I'm encountering is that my floors all slope towards one side of the house. The structure of the house was repair but not leveled by the previous owner and I have no desire to jack the house back up to level. Which brings me to my next issue. The old floors are planks laid directly across the joists with no subfloor.
With these issues noted, what would be the best method to make sure the plywood I'm laying down is level? I would rather not rip up the old plank flooring and shim the joists if I don't have to, so I'm open to any wild ideas anyone might have.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How much of a slope does the house (and joists) have? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What country are you in or what state if in the US? Presumably there would be procedures locally recognized as acceptable to deal with problems in older houses. Deviation from these could result in questions about soundness which could significantly affect resale value.

Comment: Why do you need your new floor to be perfectly level?  That is part of the charm of a 120 year old house.  You could just adjust the legs of your pool table, and every thing else should be fine.